# Configurate a second wifi conecction

Tags: wireless

I need constant wifi on my laptop for working. I use my home wifi, but I'd like to configurate Ubuntu to test the conecction constantly and, in case it doesn't work, it automatically connects to a second wifi (my phone serving as a hotspot), how could I do that? Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure about your question , but usually when you connect WiFi with your Ubuntu PC , very first it will ask for a password , with that your connection becomes trusted . So you can set one WiFi as trusted and if you don't want click forget connection to remove.

Comment: I don't want to remove the old connection, I want Ubuntu to test internet on my home Wifi, and in case it doesn't work (the router is on but without internet), Ubuntu automatically connects to other wifi network (my phone). Thanks.